# Make sequential numeric column names prefixed with a letter

Tags: r

I want to add a label to my dataset. However, the problems is that there are so many columns in my data sets so adding the labels manually is laborious.

I have 33 columns including the `label` column at the end as below.

```
features <- c("f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","f6","f7","f8","f9","f10",
              "f11","f12","f13","f14","f15","f16","f17","f18","f19","f20",
              "f21","f22","f23","f24","f25","f26","f27","f28","f29","f30",
              "f31","f32","label")
colnames(urc_training_norm) <- features
```

As you can see, typing manually the each column is annoying to add the column names that I wanted.

Is there any better way to generate these names?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean this sort of thing? `features <- c(paste0("f",as.character(1:32)), "label")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I usually do it. `sprintf` prints the numbers directly. By adding `%02d` or `%03d` you can add leading zeroes, which is helpful when dealing with large numbers :D

```
features <- c(sprintf("f%02d", seq(1,32)),"label")
colnames(urc_training_norm) <- features
```

Comment: features <- c(sprintf("f%-2d", seq(1,32)),"label")   but using paste0 function seems better here.  features <- c(paste0("f", 1:32), "label")

Answer (score 11):

You can use `paste0` command

```
    > c(paste0("f", 1:32), "label")


     [1] "f1"    "f2"    "f3"    "f4"    "f5"    "f6"    "f7"    "f8"    "f9"    "f10"   "f11"   "f12"  
    [13] "f13"   "f14"   "f15"   "f16"   "f17"   "f18"   "f19"   "f20"   "f21"   "f22"   "f23"   "f24"  
    [25] "f25"   "f26"   "f27"   "f28"   "f29"   "f30"   "f31"   "f32"   "label"
```

This will do the job

```
colnames(urc_training_norm) <- c(paste0("f", 1:32), "label")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind prefixing with `X` instead of `f`, then we can use `make.names()` function which is designed for making syntactically valid names:

```
make.names(c(1:4, "label"))
# [1] "X1"    "X2"    "X3"    "X4"    "label"
```

Or we can use `make.unique()`:

```
make.unique(c(rep("f", 4), "label"), sep = "")
# [1] "f"     "f1"    "f2"    "f3"    "label"
```